# hyperlinks control with via excel

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

I would like to control the opening of hyperlinks before they open, but whatever event I choose Sub Workbook_SheetChange or else, hyperlinks open before any event.
I searched but couldn't find how to do it. An AI pointed me towards a property Application.hyperlinks.enanble = False.... but I never found this method, even when loading or unloading the libraries mentioned by said AI.... one of Do you know of a solution to intercept the opening of hyperlinks?
Thanks in advance
///2024_02_10----

Thank you for your interest in this question. In my experience, and whatever the method of creating a hypertext line (Hypertext Hyperlink Function(...), or direct creation in the sheet. When the link is valid, it is opened before any reaction to events , notably SheetSelectionChange, so opening a hyperlink by clicking on the cell or object that contains it is not manageable. I am looking for a method that allows you to prohibit the direct opening of hyperlinks by the user, to be able to manage this opening by a function launched for example with SheetSelectionChange or by any other event. As I said in the initial question, an AI told me that the Application.hyperlinks.enable method existed for that since excel 2016, and disabled Application.hyperlinks.enable= false, it prevented the opening of links.... Despite my research, I never found this method.. And I am still looking for a solution

Comment: Are these hyperlinks manually inserted, or created with the `HYPERLINK` function? What is your end goal?

Comment: Needs some context around  "I would like to control the opening of hyperlinks before they open"  Do you want them sometimes *not* to open, or something else?  Do you have full control over the creation/content of these links?

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I completed my original question to try to be clearer

Comment: I don't think there's any way to do this short of modifying the links so they pass though a mechanism you control, so you can trap them there.

Comment: after several days of research and testing, I will end up thinking like you. what would be the method to intercept the links?. are you thinking of something like a special character or string, intercepted by sheetselectionchange, then instr(target.value,...ETC), then a code which deletes this mess of characters and sends a followhyperlink ????

Comment: Like my suggestion below

Comment: ok, thank you, I hadn't noticed that the hyperlink formula called the function, and the hyperlink... I'll try that right away.

Comment: It's curious, it's impossible to examine how the function works in step-by-step mode, the function seems to be running. I would have liked to adapt it to any type of link. URL, Document (PDF, Word etc), External link (binder or lbinder + range), and finally range. but since I can't debug...

Comment: Functions called like this seem to run in a different "context" from methods triggered in the typical way.  However you can still call LinkController from a regular Sub and get the typical debugging flow.

Comment: Obviously, this method works for a while, but for some reason that I have not determined, it ends up generating a problem which prevents the code from being controlled in debug mode, the code executes entirely without stopping at breakpoints, or in step-by-step mode. it is even impossible to launch a procedure with F5 or F8. It may be my installation but, although attractive, I must pass this methosis

Comment: In fact I opted for another solution. I created procedures which point to the object to be linked and place a character string in the cell with all the information allowing access to it as well as a series of special characters (#@&_!), which allow to identify the fact that they contain this type of information. Then with sheetselectionchange, and examination of the content of the Target, I activate the procedures which allow the link to be controlled and opened.

Answer (score 1):

Not really clear what you mean by the question, but you could do something like this:

Couple of sample worksheet hyperlink formulas:

`=HYPERLINK("#LinkController(""https:///www.google.com"")","Test")`
`=HYPERLINK("#LinkController(""https:///www.yahoo.com"")","Test")`

or like this if the URL is in a different cell
`=HYPERLINK("#LinkController(C6)","Test")`

In a regular module:

```vb
'Function to mediate clicks on worksheet hyperlinks
Function LinkController(URL)
    Debug.Print "URL: ", URL
    Set LinkController = Selection 'have to return something...
    If URL Like "*goog*" Then
        ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink URL
    Else
        MsgBox "Can't open this link"
    End If
End Function
```

Will also work with Insert > Link:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I completed my original question to try to be clearer.